# Azure Spatial Anchors: Setting up project in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, azure, arkit, azure-spatial-anchors

I am referring to this Azure documentation to develop an ARKit iOS app to create and locate Azure Spatial Anchors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/create-locate-anchors-swift

However, when I reach this step in the set-up of the project: _cloudSession?.processFrame(self.sceneView.session.currentFrame)

I receive the following error in Xcode:

> > *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SCCException', reason: ' Invalid argument. (22). Invalid argument provided. RequestCorrelationVector: . ResponseCorrelationVector: '
> > *** First throw call stack:
> > (0x18469986c 0x1996b4c50 0x1845924a4 0x106c00bac 0x104ab9ef8 0x104ab9f8c 0x1b8a3aec8 0x1b8a3d830 0x1b8a3de20 0x1b8a3e204 0x1b8ae09a0 0x1b8995958 0x1b8aa9be0 0x10c8896c0 0x10c899f14 0x1b8aa9b64 0x18796b6fc 0x187a44a80 0x1845f0dd0 0x184615fe8 0x184615378 0x18460f08c 0x18460e21c 0x1858bddf0 0x1b8995ea4 0x1b89961bc 0x1d0147cb0 0x1d0150778)
> > libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> > *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SCCException', reason: ' Invalid argument. (22). Invalid argument provided. RequestCorrelationVector: . ResponseCorrelationVector: '
> > terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

My code thus far is as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ASACloudSpatialAnchorSessionDelegate {

@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

var _cloudSession : ASACloudSpatialAnchorSession? = nil

// Set this string to the account ID provided for the Azure Spatial Anchors account resource.
let spatialAnchorsAccountId = "****************************************"

// Set this string to the account key provided for the Azure Spatial Anchors account resource.
let spatialAnchorsAccountKey = "****************************************"

// Set this string to the account domain provided for the Azure Spatial Anchors account resource.
let spatialAnchorsAccountDomain = "eastus.mixedreality.azure.com"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    sceneView.delegate = self              // set the view's delegate
    sceneView.showsStatistics = false      // show statistics
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    
    // initializing the session
    _cloudSession = ASACloudSpatialAnchorSession()
    
    // start session
    _cloudSession!.session = self.sceneView.session;
    _cloudSession!.logLevel = .information
    _cloudSession!.delegate = self;
    
    // set auth
    _cloudSession!.configuration.accountId = spatialAnchorsAccountId
    _cloudSession!.configuration.accountKey = spatialAnchorsAccountKey
    _cloudSession!.configuration.accountDomain = spatialAnchorsAccountDomain
    
 
    _cloudSession!.start()
    
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    if let cloudSession = _cloudSession {
        cloudSession.processFrame(sceneView.session.currentFrame)
    }
} 

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    // Create a session configuration
    let configuration = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()
    
    // Run the view's session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    // Pause the view's session
    sceneView.session.pause()
}
```

The sample iOS application is working for me, but following the steps of the set-up process for building a project from scratch has got me confused.

I am also unclear about this statement in the documentation: "...This object must implement the SSCCloudSpatialAnchorSessionDelegate protocol..."

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout [documentation on protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/objectivec/api/spatial-anchors/asacloudspatialanchorsessiondelegate) `ASACloudSpatialAnchorSessionDelegate` (Objective-C) for more details.

The code line `_cloudSession!.delegate = self;` specifies that the class `ViewController` is expected to follow `ASACloudSpatialAnchorSessionDelegate` protocol and it does say so:

`class ViewController: ... ASACloudSpatialAnchorSessionDelegate`
, which is already a good start.

What missing in the file is probably implementation of the methods of `ASACloudSpatialAnchorSessionDelegate` such as `anchorLocated`, `sessionUpdated`,  and `error` etc. These methods are typically called by `ASACloudSpatialAnchorSession` during its operations. You can refer to the Swift sample on how these methods are implemented.

Moreover, it seems that you may want to change

`let configuration = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()`
to
`let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()`

since it is related to world tracking.